# Fading a dotted path

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency

I am trying to create a dotted path something like this:

```
\draw [dotted] (bottom) -- (top);
```

I would like to add fading to the path such that at the bottom its solid and at the top its 30% or 40% transparent. Other lines that intersect with my dotted line should not be transparent.

I tried this:

```
\draw [dotted, fading=fade north] (bottom) -- (top);
```

But that did not work, I have also tried this answer: [Fading of horizontal lines is impossible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101974/fading-of-horizontal-lines-is-impossible) but I have two issues with that:

1. <del>The solution is not working for me, even if I start a new document and literally copy the solution over. I always see solid lines.</del> This was an issue with my pdf viewer.
2. I am not quite understand the concept behind that solution, what are the `axis` needed for and what is `\addplot+` doing?

**Update:**
While the solution in my answer below works in two cases, in two other cases I get a Latex error which says: 'Dimension too large'. All I have done was shifting the point to the right by a few centimeters.

Comment: You don't need any of those axis and addplot stuff. It is from pgfplots package for plotting and you don't need them

Comment: You are right, I just failed to realized that because my viewer was not showing the transparency.

Answer (score 1):

The following code does render transparency (if the right viewer is used)

```
\coordinate (top);

\coordinate[below=10cm of top] (bottom);

\draw [red,dotted,path fading=south] (bottom) -- (top);
```